# Laravel middleware is returning unauthenticated in production server from sub directory

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-middleware

I am sending an API request to get user detail after login
I have a project in which I am running APIs only, I placed this project in sub-directory which has name api. so front-end is running on the root which is built in react JS.

also, I have removed the API prefix from RouteServiceProvider because I don't want to call `domain.com/api/api`

**Route:**

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'], function(){
    ...

    Route::post('login','LoginController@login'); // Running successfully
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', 'LoginController@user'); // Returning 401 unauthenticated
});
```

**RouteServiceProvider**

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('api')
            ->as('api.')
            ->namespace($this->namespace."\\API")
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```

**Tried solutions**

1) I have placed `Passport::withoutCookieSerialization();` inside `boot` method in `AppServiceProvider`

2) I have placed the `Passport::$ignoreCsrfToken = true;` inside `boot` method in `AuthServiceProvider`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution myself.

I have added these lines to `.htaccess` file placed in the root of Laravel project (not public).

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```